# Passing a Python List through a SQL Statement on a Loop

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to figure out how to pass a list as a parameters through a where statement in SQL, I can not program what I am looking for, but  below is what I am looking for.

This is what I would do for one parameter....

`x = 1
sql = """Select t1,t2,t3,t4 from database where t1= ? """
cur.execute(sql,x)`

Example of what I need

```
X = [1,2,3,4]
Select t1,t2,t3,t4 from database where t1= 1
Select t1,t2,t3,t4 from database where t1= 2
Select t1,t2,t3,t4 from database where t1= 3
Select t1,t2,t3,t4 from database where t1= 4
```

Example of what I am trying that isn't working....

```
X = [1,2,3,4]
sql = """Select Select t1,t2,t3,t4 from database where t1= ? """
example=[]
i = 0
for item in X:
    while i < len(x)
        row = cur.execute(sql,item)
        i +=1
        example.append(row)
```

Comment: Are you aware about `cur.executemany`?

Comment: You have `"Select Select"`... get rid of one of them.

Comment: You also need to clarify "not working" and the `while` loop with the `i` counter is confusing me.

Comment: Can't test; `cur.execute("SELECT t1, t2, t3, t4 FROM database WHERE t1 IN ({})".format(', '.join(['?' for item in X])), X)`

Comment: What error exactly do you get? "not working" is a bit too much generic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL IN operator using pyodbc and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819356/sql-in-operator-using-pyodbc-and-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is looping through a list of IDs and appending a row to a list named `example` then you can just build a dynamic `IN` clause and retrieve the rows all at once:

```python
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
qmarks = ','.join('?' * len(x))  
print(qmarks)  # ?,?,?,?
sql = f"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE t1 IN ({qmarks})"  
print(sql)  # SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE t1 IN (?,?,?,?)
example = crsr.execute(sql, x).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be 
`cursor.execute("""Select t1, t2, t3, t4 from database where t1 in ('1', '2', '3', '4')""")`